# Magento installer setup agnostic insert

Tags: magento, installation, database-agnostic

I got through [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources) tutorial regarding Magento Setup Resources.

At some point I saw that it supports more database backends, but in the mentioned tutorial is described only the way you can **create** tables.

I would need some resources/examples regarding methods for ***inserting*** (*agnostic script*) data into previous  created tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all things Magento (and open source), your best bet is to look at how other developers, specifically the Magento core developers, do the same thing.  Here's a few examples

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Tax/sql/tax_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.2-0.7.3.php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

if (!$installer->getConnection()->fetchOne("select * from {$this->getTable('tax_class')} where `class_name`='Shipping' and `class_type`='PRODUCT'")) {
    $installer->run("
        insert  into {$this->getTable('tax_class')} (`class_name`,`class_type`) values ('Shipping','PRODUCT');
    ");
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

...

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.29-0.9.0.php
$installer->getConnection()->insert($installer->getTable('sales_flat_quote'), $quoteData);
```

You're basically running raw SQL against the database, so it'll be on you (i.e. the developer's responsibility) to keep it generic enough to run in the various SQL (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) environments.

I wouldn't recommend using standard Magento models in the setup resources.  The context Magento runs those migration scripts in doesn't match the context that models normally run in.  You may be able to get away with it, but using a normal Magento model in your setup resource script may break if the model makes assumptions about a fully bootstrapped Magento system.

You can find more examples yourself with a little searching. If you're command line savvy try this

```
$ cd app/code/core/Mage
$ find . -type f -wholename '*/sql/*'  | xargs grep -i -r insert 
$ find . -type f -wholename '*/sql/*'  | xargs ack -i insert       #if you use ack
```

Comment: Not sure it is db agnostic insert.

Answer (score 1):

You should use corresponding model to insert data. Example from `app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/data/dataflow_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php`:

```
$dataflowData = array(
    array(
        'name'         => 'Export All Products',
        'actions_xml'  => '<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">\r\n    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>\r\n</action>\r\n\r\n<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">\r\n    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>\r\n</action>\r\n\r\n<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">\r\n</action>\r\n\r\n<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">\r\n    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>\r\n    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>\r\n    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>\r\n</action>\r\n\r\n<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">\r\n    <var name="type">file</var>\r\n    <var name="path">var/export</var>\r\n    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[export_all_products.csv]]></var>\r\n</action>\r\n\r\n',
        'gui_data'     => 'a:5:{s:4:"file";a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"file";s:8:"filename";s:23:"export_all_products.csv";s:4:"path";s:10:"var/export";s:4:"host";s:0:"";s:4:"user";s:0:"";s:8:"password";s:0:"";s:7:"passive";s:0:"";}s:5:"parse";a:5:{s:4:"type";s:3:"csv";s:12:"single_sheet";s:0:"";s:9:"delimiter";s:1:",";s:7:"enclose";s:1:""";s:10:"fieldnames";s:4:"true";}s:3:"map";a:3:{s:14:"only_specified";s:0:"";s:7:"product";a:2:{s:2:"db";a:0:{}s:4:"file";a:0:{}}s:8:"customer";a:2:{s:2:"db";a:0:{}s:4:"file";a:0:{}}}s:7:"product";a:1:{s:6:"filter";a:8:{s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:3:"sku";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:1:"0";s:13:"attribute_set";s:0:"";s:5:"price";a:2:{s:4:"from";s:0:"";s:2:"to";s:0:"";}s:3:"qty";a:2:{s:4:"from";s:0:"";s:2:"to";s:0:"";}s:10:"visibility";s:1:"0";s:6:"status";s:1:"0";}}s:8:"customer";a:1:{s:6:"filter";a:10:{s:9:"firstname";s:0:"";s:8:"lastname";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:0:"";s:5:"group";s:1:"0";s:10:"adressType";s:15:"default_billing";s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";s:8:"postcode";s:0:"";s:7:"country";s:0:"";s:6:"region";s:0:"";s:10:"created_at";a:2:{s:4:"from";s:0:"";s:2:"to";s:0:"";}}}}',
        'direction'    => 'export',
        'entity_type'  => 'product',
        'store_id'     => 0,
        'data_transfer'=> 'file'
    ),
    // ... 
);

foreach ($dataflowData as $bind) {
    Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile')->setData($bind)->save();
}
```

Comment: THe original question is asking specifically about the setup resource/migration system, not about inserting product/catalog data.

Comment: Question is unclear, this answer is pretty good as it underline the fact that models should be used for inserting DATA (which is totally OK in an upgrade script.) By the way, if Michael really want to insert data the rough way, his tutorial gives him the solution : $installer->run("SQL");

Comment: I need to insert data in some custom tables (needed for a particular module) but I want to use that type of agnostic script in order to ensure compatibility with any database management system that might be used under some particular magento store.